# Anonymous function: "object is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function**

I decided to make my writeMessage() function anonymous; before it would always mess up when another instance of the writeMessage() function was created at the same time, causing text output to be jumbled (both messages being "wrote" would get put together and mixed up).

However, I've seen to have run into an error (as shown above). *The variable `object` is a jQuery object (e.g: $('#myDivElement')).*

Any ideas as to why this is? Thanks.

```
function writeMessage(message,object){
    (function(message,object,i){
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(i < message.length){
                object.append(message.substr(i,1));
                i++; 
                self(message,object,i);
            }
        }, 25);
    }(message,object,0));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var self = this;
```

Since you are calling the function without context, `self` refers to the `window` object. `window` is an object (`window.toString` should give something like `[object Window]`) and not a function, so caling `self(message,object,i)` will not work.

Instead, use this:

```
var self = arguments.callee;
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! It's working perfectly now. Didn't realize the `this` keyword referred to the `window` object in an anonymous function.

Comment: @user3029571 - The value of `this` has nothing to do with whether the function is anonymous or not.  It has entirely to do with how the function is called and whether it's called in a way that sets `this` to something other than the global object.  Since your function is not calling it in this way, `this` gets its default value.

Comment: @user3029571: Instead of `arguments.callee` you could also just give the function a name so that it'll work in strict mode where `arguments.callee` is prohibited.

Comment: @cookiemonster But that defeats the purpose of an anonymous function, does it not? Strict mode is for wimps who can't write proper code without the browser noping their face :p

Comment: No it does not. There's no particular "purpose" for it to be anonymous when you actually want to reference it. That's why we give a function a name, isn't it? Using `arguments.callee` provides no advantage, and is less portable.

Comment: @cookiemonster Ooo. I thought naming the function would make it loose its anonymity. I've went ahead and named it. Again, thanks for the help. :)

Comment: @user3029571: Yeah, the name is constrained to the scope of the function itself, not the outer function. Older IE had bugs where a copy of the function would leak out, but that shouldn't be an issue in your case. If it was, you could just set the outer name to `null`.